# Maximum value in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to get an enemy to follow my character around in AS3.

The code I have so far is:

```
enemy1.x = (enemy1.x + (character.x - enemy1.x));
enemy1.y = (enemy1.y + (character.y - enemy1.y));
```

With that code, the enemy instantly appears on top of my character every frame.

I don't want it to be instant, though. I want the enemy's movement to have a maximum value, like 2 per tick.

I know that you can make a minimum and maximum for random values, but what about for something like this?

Comment: if you divide the distance it's basically "interpolation".  So something like enemy1.x = (enemy1.x + (character.x - enemy1.x)/4); will make your enemy move 1/4th of the distance between the enemy and the character in every call (would be like a logarithmic approach, faster at a far distance slower as it approaches) at some point though you need to say the distance is small enough, if you wanted linear speed you could do something like compute the angle between the two points using atan then move some set distance along the line (y = mx+b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
enemy1.x += getMovementValue(2, character.x - enemy1.x);
enemy1.y += getMovementValue(2, character.y - enemy1.y);

function getMovementValue(maxMovement:Number, d:Number):Number{
    if(d == 0) return 0;
    return (Math.min(2, Math.abs(d))) * (d / Math.abs(d));
}
```

You just multiply the minimum between the maximum allowed distance and the absolute value of actual distance to travel by 1 or -1, depending on the current orientation.

Answer (score 0):

If the calculated value for the movement is too big then you need to limit it:

```
max_x = 2

x = (enemy1.x + (character.x - enemy1.x));
if abs(x) > max_x
    if x >0
        enemy.x = max_x
    else
        enemy.x = max_x * -1
else
    enemy.x = x
```

Make it a function and re-use for y